# Change name of generated "myfile_contourtmp0.table"

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

In a PGF axis environment, I am using

```
\addplot3[contour gnuplot={number=20}]{30-0.1*(x*x)-0.05*(y*y)};
```

This command uses [`gnuplot`](http://gnuplot.info/) to generate the file `myfile_contourtmp0.table`.

My question is: How can I attribute another name for this file?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I don't think this is possible: the name is generated so that LaTeX can know about it.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but this will break the `pgfplots` workflow since the name is hardcoded in the source file for externalization (so it seems to me)

Somewhere in the bowels of `pgfplotsplothandlers.code.tex` file, we can find the following line:

```
 \edef\pgfplotsplothandlercontourexternal@file{%
     \pgfplots@loc@TMPa_contourtmp\c@pgfplotsplothandlersurveystart@contourexternal@fileno
 }%
```

So if you can attribute another name this needs to be changed too. I don't see why you would need to change it anyhow but here it is.